# SWIFT - Get value from JSON and pass through Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, pass-data

As a title I need to pass data from a JSON to my Home class, but between the two classes there is a navigation controller
Then I would like to know how to pass data through it. Thanks to everyone for the advice.
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK81L.png). Login Class:

```
let title = list["title"] as! String
let description = list["tagline"] as! String

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let navVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let tableVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as! Home
    tableVC.title = "Test"
    tableVC.description = "Test"
}
```

Home Controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleActivity: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionActivity: UILabel!
var description = ""
var title = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titleActivity.text = nome //NIL
    descriptionActivity.text = descrizione //NIL
}
```

Comment: There is no segue in your screenshot between the LoginVC and the HomeVC. Is `prepare(for:sender:)` called? If there is one, you need to do it from the Login VC to the NavVC, not from the Button. And in the IBAction of the button, call `perform(segue: "segueName", sender: nil)`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/) post could help you. You can read it from `Passing Data Back With Properties And Functions (A ← B)`, are some solutions for what you want. Choose the better for your app's logic.